# Find the good fit measurement for Non Linear model (Gaussian, Power, Exponential and Log-Logistic)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, stat

I'm very new to stat. I'm wondering that is there a way to find the goodness fit score for non-linear functions (Gaussian, Power, Log-logistics)? I tried to used curve fit function in scipy to fit my data into the model. I know that if it's linear regression we can find R-squared. However, I really have no idea how to get the measurement if my data fit with all those functions. I did some research somebody used pseudo-R squared and some used Chi-quare. Here is my code for running gaussian and try to find the fit.

```
# X,Y  -> both are in array

x = ar(df['r'].values)
y = ar(df['D'].values)

# Parameters for Gaussian
n = len(x)
mean = sum(x*yn)/n
sigma = math.sqrt(sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n)

def gaussian(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return (a/(sigma*math.sqrt(2 * 3.14159265)))*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

# Curve fit from Scipy
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, x, yn, p0=[1, mean, sigma])

# First option :Finding best fit from Chi-square
p1 = popt[0]
p2 = popt[1]
p3 = popt[2]
chisqr = sum((yn- guassian(x,p1,p2,p3)**2/sigma**2)
dof = len(yn) - 2
GOF = 1 - chi2.cdf(chisqr,dof)

#Second option : R^2 = SS_reg/SS_tot
y_fit = [gaus(xi, *popt) for xi in x]
y_bar = np.sum(yn)/len(y)
ssreg = np.sum([ (yihat - ybar)**2 for yihat in y_fit])
sstot = np.sum([ (yi - ybar)**2 for yi in yn])
results = ssreg / sstot
```

Another question:
Are my model correct?

```
    Gaussian: 
    (a/(sigma*math.sqrt(2 * 3.14159265)))*exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

    Power:
    x*exp(-b)

    Exponential:
    exp(-b*x)

    Logarithm
    :exp(-x) / (1+exp(-x))**2
```

Are all this correct? I got the low GOF score which the graph from the result of curve_fit looks so fit. Thank you so much for your time. Really Appreciate

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow, can you post a [mcve], so we can see what you mean by low GOF?